# What is the key elements that make westerners have some better characteristics over asian

Tags: history-of-psychology, social-neuroscience

I want to get your ideas or any suggestions of references (books, articles..) that I can read to help me answer this question:

We all know that westerners are more open while Asian people are more shy and close this is a real characteristic but not saying which one is better. But  beside many aspects westerners are learning from Asian, I also observed that westerners have some characteristics that not very popular to Asian, the things they often do that end up making their social develops faster and more modern:

- From very long time before, they make ships and risk their lifes to cross oceans find out new lands. (that's why now US is born, and many asian countries is dominated in the history).
- They find new places in the wilds, build good infrastructures, social and laws.
- Where they go, they can easily determine where is a good place to stay, as good or sometimes better than the local people.
- They quite dare to try new things, get risk of old stuffs and thinkings. Try out new things.

But we also know that westerns social also go through the dark period (when there are kings and not very develop social system), similar as Asian.

So is this because of the genes (DNA) or the type of monkeys they are develop from (so the brain structure different?) or the climate, food, environment differences or the social system, different way of education... ? What are key elements that drive the differences in these two culture, people?

(Please ignore any racist or comparison on who is superior, I know everybody has their own goods) but I just want to find out the reason for these facts. I live in Asia.

Comment: You're asking for non-racist answers, but your question is so racist.

Comment: I am sorry that you feel so from my question. I'm also Asian living in asia, pls just ignore this feeling, saving time for the answers. I just want to find causes for a fact (you can read history). It is the same as the fact is that Jewish won the most number of Nobel prize and people did write books trying to answer why, to help people to learn from that. Same thing here, it is not the matter of what you feel about the question, but the fact and the answer for it is important, and I want to focus on that. Thank you !

Comment: Please also take note that I also mentioned many aspects in my questions like social conditions, geometry conditions that could be the causes , not only nature characteristics. (I google about racist is " the belief that a particular race is superior or inferior to another", and in this case, there is no belief like that showing in my question).

Comment: @YvonneLiew, there is nothing racist about asking why certain racial groups perform better in certain dimensions.  Please take care not to engage in knee-jerk reactions, as they tend to lower the general level of discourse.

Comment: re this question being placed on hold:  I find this to be a strange decision.  This doesn't strike me as being opinion-based, but rather as asking for primary sources on a contentious subject.

Comment: @ Arnon et.al. : you close such kind of question is the reason why I cannot find answer for my question any where on the internet. Such a platform like stackexchange should be the place where people can find all the answer for all their wonder for broaden the knowledge.